# Vector of pointers to class methods QT

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, vector

How to create a vector of pointers to class methods? I have my vector as class's member (vector must store pointers of methods with different return values and signatures):

```
QVector<void(*)()> m_operationsVector;
```

Then I have example class's method:

```
QString sampleMethod(QJsonObject &jsonObject, QString delim);
```

And I'm trying to add pointer of to this method to vector:

```
m_operationsVector.push_back(sampleMethod);
```

But unfortunately during adding this pointer to vector I'm getting this error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If Foo is your class then you can try as follows: 

`QVector<void(const Foo&)> m_operationsVector;`
`m_operationsVector.push_back(&Foo::processSetBlindStateRequest);`

Comment: _vector must store pointers of methods with different return values and signatures_ and how do you decide how to call them?

Comment: Have you considered to use signal/slot?

Comment: To decide I will use for example QPair and I will search method pointer by key. Can you explain how use signal/slots with my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all pointer to class method is defined differently, so this vector should look like this:

```
QVector<void (A::*)()> m_operationsVector;
```

Secondly in C++11 it is more handy to use `std::function` and lambdas:

```
QVector<std::function<void()>> m_operationsVector;

operationsVector.push_back([this]() { this->someMethod(); });
```

Thirdly when this is combined with JSon this looks suspicious. What are you doing? This looks like [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).